# React: Why do chained computed's always recompute even if intermediate values don't change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I may have phrased the question poorly, but I am trying to understand the tracing behavior I am seeing through a chain of a few computeds.

If I have a chain of e.g. `observable` -> `computed1` -> `computed2`, when the observable is modified, I see an invalidation in `computed2` even if `computed1` has returned the same value.

A contrived example is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/trace-forked-syy694?file=/src/index.js

My concern here is if `computed2` is expensive to compute, and it is only dependent on the value of `computed1`, why should it need to recompute if the intermediate computed value has not actually changed but the root observable has?

Am I misunderstanding the trace output, is the computation not actually run and mobx is still just returning a cached value? Is there some way to verify this? I understand when calling `trace()` in a render func it will show as having been invalidated, but it will only re-render based on the comparison/equality of the observed values and this is easy to see by `console.log`-ing in the render func, do `computed`'s work in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a bug in `trace`, you are using some older versions of the library, if you switch to the latest ones you will see that it works fine and does not log invalidation for `total`.

Also if you just add `console.log` to the `total` computed you will see that actually it works as expected, it does not recompute and always returns cached value. So it's just `trace` bug (or version mismatch or whatever).